# Can I turn the SSH on Ubuntu Mate on headlessly?

Tags: ubuntu

I don't have a monitor just at the hand, but I want to use my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Mate... How do I activate the SSH on it?
When trying to ssh to it, it says 'Connection refused'

Comment: IIRC it already is enabled the change only affected Raspbian. Have you tried connecting to it?

Comment: @SteveRobillard But it gives me 'Connection Refused' when trying...

Comment: You can try adding an ssh file (no extension) to the boot directory and rebooting, but I suspect that it is either not installed or not started.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yeah, I have tried that as well...

Comment: If you must do this headless you may be better off using Raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unluckily you have to do first configuration with the hdmi and enable the ssh service.
This because a recent patch that disabled ssh on first boot.
Regards, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

After you attach a monitor to your Pi3, open up a terminal and enter in

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

I recommend installing ufw on any Pi device

```
sudo apt install ufw
```

Now to allow ssh connections:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```